# Pagination for Table PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I would like to know how can I insert the pagination for table here. As you will see it is still MYSQL which already depreciated since the owner of the is still working doesn't want to update.

I'm not the developer his system. Can you help me to paginate this part? I'm not familiar with old mysql, since I already started with MYSQLi

```
#TABLE

     if ($userRow['type'] == 'ADMIN') {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `complaints` ORDER BY `date_modify` DESC, `status` DESC  LIMIT 60";

                 #country 


                } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `complaints` WHERE `country` in (".$sqlp.")  ORDER BY `date_modify` DESC, `status` DESC ";

                }




            if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


              if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
                    echo "<script> alert('No Records Found, Please try again!')</script>"; 

                    } else {


                     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

                    {
                   echo "<tbody><tr>";
                 if($userRow['type']=='ADMIN'){

                     echo "<td><a href=\"admin-update.php?id=".$row['id']."\">".$row['ticket']."</td>";

                  } else {

                echo "<td><a href=\"followup.php?id=".$row['id']."\">".$row['ticket']."</td>"; 
                }
                echo "<td>".$row['c_Fname']." ".$row['c_Lname'];
                echo "<td>".$row['section']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['topic']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['originator']."</td>";

                echo "<td>".$row['current']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['date_open']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['date_modify']."</td>";

                if ($row['status'] == 'OPEN') {
                    $date_o=$row['date_open'];
                $date_today=date('Y-m-d h:i A');

                $diff = strtotime($date_today) - strtotime($date_o);
                $old = $diff/(60*60*24);

                echo "<td>".floor($old)."</td>";

                } else {

                    echo "<td> --- </td>";
                }  





               echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";

    }
       }
         }               

    ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Offtopic :- Why are you not using datatables?

Comment: @Chris yes I know, although I really  don't know `mysql_` as I said it I started using `mysqli_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with *offset* and *limit* in the query:

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Pass a variable called `page` by *GET*:

**HTML**

```
<a href="URL?page=2">Page 2</a>
```

**PHP**

```
"SELECT * FROM complaints
        LIMIT 10 OFFSET " . (intval($_GET['page'])-1) * 10
```

> Page 1 => Records between 0 and 10
>
> Page 2 => Records between 11 and 20
>
> Page 3 => Records between 21 and 30
>
> [...]

With page 2, you'll get records between 11 and 20.